# Symfony2 Soft Update object

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony-2.8

In DoctrineExtensions there is a SoftDeleteable allows to "soft delete" objects.
There is a Bundle using for create a soft update an entity doctrine symfony2 ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *same* bundle there is [loggable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md). Which supports reverting an object to a previous version. Which would be a 'soft update' pretty much.